# why my discord bot seems like has no command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

i trying to make a discord bot. i add join and leave command but is not working. I can't find where the mistake is, can you help me?

```
import discord
import discord.client
from discord.ext import commands


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = "i just removed for privacy"
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)


    @client.event
    async def on_ready(pass_context=True):
        print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')

    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def join(ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()

        else:
            await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel.")

    @client.command()
    async def leave(ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client:
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnet()
            await ctx.send("Okay i leave :'( ")
        else:
            await ctx.send("I'm not in a voice channel")

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

bot works like normal and i can read discord chat on pycharm. But it didn't care the commands i wrote.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npWwY.png)

Comment: What's not working? Is there an error? Does the bot crash? Or do you see behavior you were not expecting?

Comment: nothing for example when i write .join nothing happened.

Comment: First, enable ALL THE INTENTS, discord intents are weird and there's no harm in enabling them all. Second check that messages are coming through, log all commands and messages and see if theyre correct. I hope this helps

Comment: i just create new bot with same setting and it worked